# Updating PHP version, old sites use magic_quotes_gpc

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web server running PHP 5.3 with around 50 or so web sites all of which have a custom coded CMS which makes use of magic_quotes_gpc. None of the CMS' add slashes or strip slashes.

However I now want to update to the latest PHP version which no longer supports magic_quotes. If I update the PHP, suddenly all those web sites will start getting failed queries due to unescaped quotes.

Is there some solution to this, other than going in and having every client's web site recoded to find every instance of a query and add/strip slashes to everything or mysql_real_escape string everything?

Kindest,

Scott

Comment: Are you sure it's such a good idea to run such sloppy code in the first place? It sounds like a security issue waiting to happen.

Comment: [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/auto_prepend_file) and either the same workaround ([`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) on the input arrays, or better yet the right escaping function after DB connection).

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen - I don't really know if it's a good idea or not. I wouldn't know if it is sloppy. I don't have anything to judge it by. My sites perform well and my clients love them, and the vast majority of them do not contain sensitive data. I like to think I code well, but I am always looking to get better, hence why I'm asking :) Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I guess my goal was to avoid having to edit any of my old sites. I guess that's not a possibility?

Comment: As @mario said the only feasible way to be to reimplement the magic quotes functionality on the PHP side. The better way would be to convert all you queries to prepared statements.